# Вопрос по организации DNS Proxy Server

Tags: dns

Появилась задача перевести все ДНС ПК на один определенный, поднятый на Bind9 DNS сервер.

Задача такова:

- Поднять DNS сервер (не важно Bind9 или что там)
- Прослушивать трафик к определенным сайтам, а так же фильтровать запросы и результаты от запросов на определенные слова. К примеру: украл, удалил, получил, отправил и т.п.

DNS успешно поднял на Bind9. Получаю запрос, передаю ip оригинального сайта. А что делать дальше ? Что за ПО необходимо?

Comment: На будущее, проверьте хотя бы опечатки в сообщении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, речь об http трафике? Тогда могу предложить Privoxy. Этот прокси-сервер позволяет писать собственные фильтры на основе регулярных выражений, которые смогут отфильтровать получаемое пользователями содержимое. В качестве бонуса - с его помощью вы сможете избавиться от рекламы на сайтах. Но если вам нужна лишь возможность фильтровать содержимое - то отключите в конфигурации все стандартные actionsfile и создайте собственный. В нём нужно будет указать имя фильтра и перечень сайтов, к которым он применяется. В файле user.filter создайте фильтр под этим же именем и пропишите туда необходимое регулярное выражение.

Comment: Но как сделать что бы при запросе на DNS .. Передавался ip прокси и при запросе на прокси выводился тот сайт который запрашивал клиент ?

Comment: @Alex Mixayelovich Sokolov - возможно я не полностью понял цель, но при чём здесь DNS? Какие именно запросы нужно фильтровать? Из содержимого сайтов или из их названия? Можно пример, пожалуйста? Нужно прослушивать весь HTTP трафик к сайтам, и если в нём встречаются слова вроде "украл", "удалил", "получил", "отправил", то нужно это определённым способом отфильтровать, что бы пользователь увидел что-то другое в итоге? Но это же не имеет отношения к системе доменных имён.

Comment: Вопрос уже решил , спасибо большое. Ваш совет помог.